# Make image accessible in all folders in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to know where to play my images in cakephp folder structure and what image URL should I use that it is accessible in all folders structure of cakephp?

```
img url="" alt=""/>
```

The problem I face is, I need to specify the direct URL of the image in my main layout, and I want it to be reflected in all pages, but then i realised some pages the image is not showing. Please assist. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> where to play my images in cakephp folder structure

wherever you wish. images have no direct relation to cakephp. 
`/img/` folder in the root folder of your web server seems okay.

> what image URL should I use that it is accessible in all folders?

an absolute one. but not URL but just path. say, you have `logo.png` in your `/img/` folder. So write it as `/img/logo.png` and it would be accessible from anywhere

Comment: I found the answer myself, I should use the image helper.

    <?php echo $html->image('', array('alt' => ''));?>

It works now.